# SQL query to show rows that are 60+ in the past

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a row in my database with the datetime as

```
2013-11-07 13:04:57
```

then i am running this Query:

```
SELECT * from customer_communication 
    WHERE customer_seq = '276' 
        and datetime < DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 60 DAY) 
    order by datetime DESC
```

so it should not be returning this row

i want to show all rows with a datetime that are 60+ days in the past

Comment: wht sql server do you ues? ms? mysql?

Comment: Why do you say that it should not be returning that row?

Comment: @PatrickQ it shouldnt be because it is not 60+ days in the past. the datetime it has is within 60 days of todays date

Comment: @charlie You should try counting back from today again.  60 days ago was 2013-11-10

Comment: good news and bad news for you @charlie.  The good news is your code is correct.  The bad news is you seem to think that 2013-11-07 was not more than 60 days ago which can only mean one thing... You've accidentally traveled into the future!  Welcome.

Comment: there is now a row with the datetime of 2013-10-30 11:22:40 and its still showing

Answer (score 0):

The date `2013-11-07 13:04:57` is more than 60 days in the past:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 60 DAY);
=> 2013-11-10
```

Any date on or before November 10th will be displayed (from January 9th)

```
# Show difference in days.
SELECT DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()),'2013-11-07');
=> 63
```

Additionally, you should be using the `<=` comparator if you wish to show rows that have a date set to exactly 60 days ago from the current day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your current query will select rows that are older than one `datetime` value. You need to change comparison sign  to:

```
 datetime > DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

And  date 2013-11-07 13:04:57  more than 60 days in the past.

Comment: The question asks to only select rows that are 60 days in the past or greater. Your SQL comparator tells the database to look for rows within 60 days of the current date. I would say the better comparator would be `<=`

Comment: No, this query will return value 60 days in the past

Comment: `SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY > NOW()` returns `1` (true). From this, we can see that earlier dates are **less than** later dates. If you're looking for dates earlier than a certain date, you must use `<` against it. Your query is explained as: where the row's `datetime` column **is more recent than** 60 days before today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEDIFF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

For example,

DATEDIFF(date1, date2) < 60