# PHP/SQL Show rows that are 60 days plus in the past

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a `datetime` column `(Y-m-d H:i:s)`

I want to be able to show all rows that have a datetime column that is 60 days plus in the past

i have tried this but it doesn't seem to be showing the correct rows:

```
SELECT * from customer_communication WHERE datetime < DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 60 DAY) order by datetime DESC
```

There is a `customer` column in this table too because each customer will have multiple rows. each time they are contacted it adds a new row for that customer so will i need to group by `customer` or group by `datetime`?

Comment: What *is* the result, if not the correct rows?

Comment: He means what is the query returning?  Are there any results, too many results, or an error?

Comment: no error, too many results. for example, i have a row with a datetime of 2014-01-09 17:24:46 which it is returning when it shouldn't. it should only return rows when the datetime column is 60 days plus in the past

Comment: tip: `DATE(now())` might as well just be `CURDATE()`

Comment: Quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022947/sql-query-to-show-rows-that-are-60-in-the-past and similar username to the author of that question. hmmmm….

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear.  I am interpreting it as "get all customers that haven't had a communication in the past 60 days".  The logic for this is to aggregate by the customer and look at the *maximum* communication date:

```
SELECT customer
from customer_communication
group by customer
having max(datetime) < DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
order by max(datetime) DESC;
```